# Meteor cross platform: different output on web and iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, meteor, mobile, react-redux

I am trying to run the code for website and mobile app(iOS). I am using meteor with react and redux as well.

When I run on web, condition 1 becomes true and it runs. When I run on mobile (simulator iOS), the condition 1 becomes false and it prints running here. 
I am very confused in this problem. What I think is that as website loads slowly as compared to mobile app, the list is prepared by call to method.js and thus, condition 1 becomes true. But for mobile, it is not happening.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
      List: state.State.List
   }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getList(Id){
      dispatch(getList(Id))
    },
  }
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    let Id = nextProps.chapter[0].listOf;
    this.props.getList(Id)
  }
}
             {this.props.list && !_.isEmpty(this.props.list) //condition 1
              ?

              this.props.list.map((title) => (
                <Tile
                  key={title._id}
                  onClick={()=>{
                    this.openPlay(title)
                  }}
                >
                </Tile>
              ))
              :
              <div>
                {this.props.list && lodash.get(this.props.list, 'length') === 0?
                  <span>nothing available</span>
                  :
                  <span> running here </span>

                }
              </div>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this function as a callback when your list gets ready

Comment: oh great and last you were at "HKU JOCKEY CLUB STUDENT VILLAGE III, 9 LUNG WAH ST, KENNEDY TOWN, HONG KONG"

Comment: Okay this is a bit creepy now.